# Is there a shortcut to Miller's algorithm?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Consider an elliptic curve $E: y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ over some finite field $F_{q^k}$ and a point $P$ on $E$ of order $n$.

Miller's algorithm tells us how to efficiently construct a rational function $f_{n,P}(x,y)$ on $E$ with divisor $div f = n [P]  - n [\mathcal{O}]$.

I have worked through examples and exercises and have understood how and why Miller's algorithm works.

But I cannot answer the following question: Why can't we just take $f_{n,P} = (y-y_P)^n$? It obviously has an $n^{\rm th}$ order root at $P$ and $n^{\rm th}$ order pole at $\mathcal{O}$. It's also obvious that it doesn't have any other poles or roots, because only the point $P$ has $y$-coordinate $y_P$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every statement you've claimed is "obvious" is false at least some of the time.

First, $y-y_P$ does not have a zero of order $1$ at $P$ for some choices of $P$. For instance, for any point $P$ with horizontal tangent line, $y-y_P$ vanishes to order two at $P$. Next, $y-y_P$ has a pole of order three at $O$: the line $V(Y-y_PZ)$ has three points of intersection with your elliptic curve away from $Z=0$; the line $V(Z)$ has a triple intersection at $O$; thus their ratio has a triple pole at $O$.